# Python - comparing imported values

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to import the list from the file, read it line by line (already works). Each line containing a string representing a list. 
I have to execute couple of tasks on it, however I got twisted and I dont know why below doesn't work. It gives me the following error :

> ```
> ErrorCode:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
> if len(n) != len(str(n + 1)):
> TypeError: must be str, not int
> ```

```
    f = open('listy.txt', 'r')  
    content = f.read().split('\n')


    for n in content: 
        n.split(',')
        ## checking lengh
        if len(n) != len(str(n + 1)):
            print('Different lengh')
        else:
            print('All fine.')
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, `n.split(",")` does nothing if you don't store it somewhere (e.g. `your_list = n.split(",")`). Now, the question is what are you trying to achieve with `if len(n) != len(str(n + 1))`?

Comment: I am trying to compare the length of each row in the file I am importing. So first setting the /n as an line separator, then separating n in the list by defining n.split(,).

Comment: _Compare the length of each row_ with what? Itself? Other rows? Elements within the row?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
n.split(',')
if len(n) != len(str(n + 1)):
```

to:

```
n = n.split(',')
len(n[0]) != len(n[1]):
```

and don't forget to close your file with a `f.close()`
Better even, use `with`, example:

```
with open('listy.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read().split('\n')
```

you do not need a `close()` method when using `with`